# SSL Certificate for a service to connect to AWS RDS fails with hostname not in Altnames

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ssl, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I have a Kubernetes service with externalIP which points to an RDS instance
The service name is `rds`

We are using pods with hostname as `rds.default.svc.cluster.local` to connect to the database using a DNS redirect using the above service. It works fine without SSL but for SSL to work it also needs the Host Name, which in this case is not visible and the certificate check fails.

Is there a way to get the ExternalName from the endpoint `rds.default.svc.cluster.local`. we know that it works if we directly provide the hostname =  but this makes it a lot difficult to manage for each service running in Kubernetes.
Service calling this host is using sequelize to establish a TLS connection

**YAML for ExternalIP service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rds
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalName: <endpoint>.rds.amazonaws.com
  ports:
  - name: rds-aurora
    port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5432
  type: ExternalName
```

**Error**

```
[queryReportMessage]: Error occured: SequelizeConnectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: rds.default.svc.cluster.local. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.<URL>.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, you will not be able to do what you're looking for. read the warning section here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname

Comment: Yeah, I found a way to do this using DNS entries or using the exact endpoint name